# Ring of continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$, maximal ideal, quotient

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $I(S) = \{f \in \mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R})  \ |  \ \ \forall x \in S: f(x)=0\}$

I've already proven that it is an ideal in the ring $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R})$.

However, I have troubles proving that if $I(S)$ is maximal, then it must have the form  $I(c), \ c \in \mathbb{R}$. The second problem is proving that $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R})/I(S) \cong \mathcal{C}(S)$. I know that an ideal $M$ of a ring $R$ is maximal $\iff$ $R/M$ is a field. But that doesn't help me here, does it?

Comment: sorry @Don, what is $S$?

Comment: Showing that an ideal of the form $I(S)$ is maximal iff $S$ is a singleton set isn't hard. However, not all maximal ideals are of that form.

Comment: @Avitus I've had some problems with that, too. But not knowing what S is didn't matter when I was proving that $I(S)$ is an ideal. I assume it is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Could you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Presumably you are not being asked to prove $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R})/I(S) \cong \mathcal{C}(S)$ -- you are being asked to prove that the *specific* map $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R})/I(S) \to \mathcal{C}(S)$ induced by the restriction map $f \mapsto f|_S$ is an isomorphism. This is not true in general, although it is in a nice special case.... It should be obvious this map is injective, so think about what surjectivity would imply.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But all the proofs I've seen here used the fact that $[0,1]$ is compact.

Comment: @Hurkyl Did you mean the map $\mathcal{C} (\mathbb{R}) \ni f \rightarrow f(c) \in \mathbb{R}$ for a certain $c$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the zero set of a continuous function is closed, we have $I(S) = I(\overline{S})$ for every subset $S \subset \mathbb{R}$. Therefore, it is advisable (and common practice) to only consider closed $S$ for the vanishing ideals.

Now, it is easy to see that $S_1 \subset S_2 \Rightarrow I(S_2) \subset I(S_1)$. In particular, $I(S) \subset I(\{c\})$ for every $c \in S$. Since $I(\{c\}) \neq \mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R})$, if $I(S)$ is maximal, then we must have $I(S) = I(\{c\})$ for every $c\in S$. But if $c\neq d$, then $I(\{c\}) \neq I(\{d\})$, for example $x \mapsto (x-c)$ lies in $I(\{c\})$, but not in $I(\{d\})$. That means, a necessary condition for $I(S)$ to be maximal is that $S$ is a singleton set. That this condition is also sufficient is not hard to see.

It is, however, worth pointing out that not all maximal ideals of $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R})$ are of this form.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just out of curiosity, what other forms can maximal ideals of this ring have?

Comment: Let us call a $Z$-filter a collection $\mathscr{F}$ of closed sets with the properties $\varnothing\notin\mathscr{F},\, \mathbb{R}\in\mathscr{F}$, and $S,T\in\mathscr{F}\Rightarrow S\cap T\in\mathscr{F}$ as well as $S\in\mathscr{F}, S\subset T\Rightarrow T\in\mathscr{F}$ for closed $T$. For a $Z$-filter $\mathscr{Z}$, let $I(\mathscr{Z}) = \{f : f^{-1}(0) \in\mathscr{Z}\}$. Then $I$ is an ideal. The family of $Z$-filters is partially ordered by inclusion, and we have $\mathscr{Z}\subset\mathscr{W}\Rightarrow I(\mathscr{Z})\subset I(\mathscr{W})$. A maximal $Z$-filter with respect to this

Comment: partial order is called a $Z$-ultrafilter. The maximal ideals of $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R})$ are exactly the $I(\mathscr{U})$ for $Z$-ultrafilters $\mathscr{U}$. $I(S)$ is the ideal $I(\mathscr{S})$, where $\mathscr{S} = \{ T : S \subset T\}$ (again, $T$ closed), and the $Z$-filters generated by the singletons $\{c\}$ are the fixed $Z$-ultrafilters. Every $Z$-filter is contained in a $Z$-ultrafilter, and considering any $Z$-ultrafilter containing the filter generated by the family $[n,\infty)$ shows that there are free $Z$-ultrafilters.